# Hyper-v core can see network devices but network devices can't see Hyper-v core

Tags: networking, ping, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Having a little issue with Hyper-v core.

Network set up, connected directly to main router, I can ping all devices successfully from the Hyper-v cmd but can not ping the Hyper-v box from any other device.

Any ideas?

Running Hyper-v 2012 r2

Comment: Why do you need to ping the Hyper-V host? The absence or presence of a response is pretty meaningless except to tell you that the host responds to pings.

Comment: Can't connect to remote desktop when turned on, can't connect with Hyper-v manager, ping is the first thing to check but since I can't do that something is very wrong. Unless I'm very mistaken and MS are doing something very strange.

Comment: Depending on the network and firewall profile, ICMP is disabled by default in Windows. Chasing ICMP instead of the "real" issue is often a wild goose chase. Troubleshoot the actual connectivity problem rather than spending time trying to figure out why pings don't work.

Comment: Fair enough, the router can see the server, I can see the server in the list of connected devices. Could it be as simple as I'm trying to connect to the RDS using a home version of Windows 10? Might try the Windows 7 Ultimate copy I've got.

Comment: My guess is that the server is using the Public network and firewall profile and the applicable rules for the connection types you're attempting are disabled for that firewall profile. Look at the network profile the server is using and look at the applicable firewall rules (RDP, etc.) for the corresponding firewall profile.

Comment: How do I do that from cmd? I can't find anything other than full server 2012

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72648/discussion-between-chris-and-joeqwerty).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a firewall issue. Try Corefig to manage Hyper-v core -it's very useful: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=corefig